# Java Swing Label Overlapping

Tags: java, swing

```java
public class Solution{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        MyGraphic frame = new MyGraphic();
        frame.setComponents();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
    }
}
class MyGraphic extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton b;
    JTextField t;
    JLabel l;
    public MyGraphic(String s){

        super(s);
    }
    public MyGraphic(){

        super();
    }
    public void setComponents(){

        b = new JButton("Action");
        t = new JTextField();
        l = new JLabel("Name");
        this.setLayout(null);
        l.setBounds(30, 50, 50, 20);
        t.setBounds(100, 50, 150, 20);
        b.setBounds(100, 100, 70, 20);
        this.add(b);
        this.add(t);
        this.add(l);
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        String name = t.getText();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Your name is "+name);
        label.setBounds(50, 150, 200, 30);
        this.add(label);
    }
}
```

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1dKM.png)
In this image link name are overlapping. First, I entered "Sagar Tanwar" then I entered "Sumit Kumar" and these name are overlapping. Please tell me, How to remove previous entered Label. You can check image using this image link.

Comment: I can recommend this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64087446/10951752). It is not a good idea to set absolute values.

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout manager. Add the label to be used for the name to the GUI with an empty string as its text. Then when you want to display the name you just set the text, instead of createing a new label. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should heed the advice in the comments to your question. Nonetheless, the simplest way to fix your problem, using the code you have already written, is to make `label` a member of class `MyGraphic` rather than a local variable in method `actionPerformed()`, i.e.

```java
class MyGraphic extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JLabel label;
    // Rest of the class code
```

Then, in method `actionPerformed()` simply set the text of the `label`.

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (label == null) {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(50, 150, 200, 30);
        this.add(label);
    }
    String name = t.getText();
    label.setText("Your name is "+name);
}
```

Comment: If I want to run a method or perform some action when I click on exit button (x) of JFrame. Please tell me, What should I do for this?

Comment: @SagarRajput that is a different question. Please post a new question. Write what you want to happen when the user clicks on the X button of the `JFrame`.